# Is my matricial representation for the system of equations $x + y = 1$ and $x - y = 2$ correctly written as well as my solution procedure?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'd like to know if I'm interpreting systems of equations correctly.

Let's say we have $$x + y = 1 \\ x - y = 2.$$

Is the proper matrix/vector notation then
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    1 & -1
  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y
  \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
     2
  \end{bmatrix}$$
and thus the solution can be calculated by left-multiplying by the inverse-matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have correctly written the matricial representation of the proposed system of linear equations. However it is not always possible to invert the coefficient matrix. Fortunately, this is the case in the given example. You can also try to apply Gaussian elimination, which is faster than inverting in general.

As to its geometrical interpretation, the solution corresponds to the point of intersection from the lines $x + y = 1$ and $x - y = 2$. In general, there are two possibilities (when working on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$): either the lines are parallel (or coincide) or they intersect at one point only. Can you extend such interpretation to the case of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Comment: How do you "know" it's accurate to represent a system this way? How do you prove it?

Comment: @StackQuest I guess you are not familiar with the notion of matrix multiplication. If that is the case, you can check its definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication).

Comment: I'm familiar with matrix multiplication, I'm not questioning that. I'm wondering how you "know" you've applied matrix multiplication correctly. Because, for instance, I could represent $x + y$ as the dot product of some vector with itself too, like $(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y}).$ So how do we know we're interpreting everything correctly?

Comment: @StackQuest A simple way to realize it: we cannot have functions such as $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{y}$ in the entries, because we are dealing with linear combinations. If you do not remember the definition of linear combination, I advise you to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination) reference.

Comment: I think it's perfectly feasible to have a linear combination of non-linear functions.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with a linear combination of non-linear functions, or functions that are non-linear in a vector. You can add two vectors of non-linear functions. Additionally, how do you know it's not accurate to represent the system as \begin{bmatrix}
    x & y \\
    x & -y
  \end{bmatrix} instead?

Comment: @StackQuest As far as I know, in the context of linear algebra, the coefficients of a linear combination have to be scalars.

Comment: But vectors in a general vector space can be of any variable. Look, here's a vector \begin{bmatrix}
    t^2 \\
     \log(t)
  \end{bmatrix} nothing wrong with that. That's still a vector, it still obeys linear algebra.

Comment: @StackQuest I think you are misinterpreting things. A system of linear equations is a set of linear combinations of variables whose values we are interested in knowing. That is why they are called linear systems. On the other hand, you can have systems of equations that are not linear:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + y^{2} = 1\\
x + y = 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
However they are not linear. That is the key point to be considered.